# What is connected apps?

Tags: apex, administration, connected-apps, remote-site

What are Connected apps and remote site settings and what is the difference between them? How can we do integration by using these two concepts? Can anyone please give one real-time example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Connected apps`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Connected_Apps):

- Used for making connection from outside to Salesforce.
- Example: For accessing Salesforce from third party app, a connected app can be used by them to make a connection and access Salesforce.

[`Remote Site Settings`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_remotesitesetting.htm):

- Enables callout to external site (from Salesforce), when Site URL is added to remote site setting.
- Example: For making callout to a external URL, it must be registered to remote site. Otherwise the call would simply fail.